# Pass HTML Table Row Value to Javascript function on load

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

```
<html>
    <td id="test" onload="GetValue('{{name}}')"></td>
</html>
<script>
    function GetValue(value){
        value+="Hello";
        document.getElementById("test").innerText=value;
    }
</script>
```

The goal is to have table row as "JohnHello" directly on page load.
I am using Handlebars and let's suppose "John" has been passed on the {{name}} variable.

Answer (score 1):

The [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event is fired for the window... And some other elements like `<img>`... But not on a `<td>`.

In the below snippet, I used the `onload` attribute on the `<body>`. That is because it directly belongs to `window`. You can target it using  `window.document.body`.

Additionnaly, I would suggest you to test using valid HTML. So to have a `<td>` inside a `<tr>` and a `<table>`... And the `<script>` tag inside the `<body>`.

That will spare you time for sure.

```html
<html>

<body onload="GetValue('john')">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="test"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <script>
    function GetValue(value) {
      value += "Hello";
      document.getElementById("test").innerText = value;
    }
    
    // This log is to show that <body> directly belongs to window
    console.log(window.document.body)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```